# Flutter Model design pattern

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a `Product` Model

```
class Product {
  int id;
  String title;
  double mrp;

  Product(this.id, this.title, this.mrp);

  factory Product.fromJson(int id, String title, double mrp) {
    return Product(id, title, mrp);
  }
}
```

I have different json structure for API calls when i get `json` data as response from server -

1st Example

```
{
  "id": 523,
  "title": "test",
  "mrp": 23.25
}
```

2nd Example :

```
{
  "id" : 523,
  "title" : "test",
  "mrp" : 23.25
  "discountedPrice" : 23.00
}
```

3rd Example :

```
{
  "id" : 523,
  "title" : "test",
  "mrp" : 23.25
  "availableForSale" : true
}
```

4th Example :

```
{
  "id" : 523,
  "title" : "test",
  "mrp" : 23.25
  "firstCharacterTitle" : "T"
}
```

As you can see i have different new field like `discountedPrice` `firstCharacterTitle` `availableForSale` API structure in different fetching call of `API`. and it can be many others in other scenario.

What should i do with `Product` Model in different cases as i have only 3 permanent fields `id` `title` `mrp` but all others are dependent on scenario ? Should i keep increasing field in my model or anything else? What is the best Practise?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for longer answer.

You have 2 options

1. adding those extra parameters and make them nullable.

```
class Product {
 int id;
 String title;
 double mrp;
 String? firstCharacterTitle;

 Product(this.id, this.title, this.mrp, {this.firstCharacterTitle});

 factory Product.fromJson(
   int id,
   String title,
   double mrp, {
   String? firstCharacterTitle,
 }) {
   return Product(id, title, mrp, firstCharacterTitle: firstCharacterTitle);
 }
}
```

2. Or work with something dynamic

```
class Product {
  int id;
  String title;
  double mrp;
  Map<String, dynamic> extraParams;

  Product(this.id, this.title, this.mrp, this.prms);

  factory Product.fromJson(int id, String title, double mrp, Map<String, dynamic> prms) {
    return Product(id, title, mrp, prms);
  }
}
```

I also recommend using [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable). Cause your fromJson method is not truly fromJson, but it's taking already converted Json parameters.

Comment: Why do we use model? Why shouldn't we use json response directly? I cant understand why there is extra layer of model.

Comment: You dont really have to if dont wanna to. But it's good practice, cause its adding extra layer safety. If you using json directly, you have check if specific parameter exists if its type is right. If you convert json to model in first place you dont have to do those things